# Multiple greek letters in one legend line

Tags: r, label, legend

I have the following piece of R code:

```
y1=rnorm(10,0,1)
y2=rnorm(10,0,1)
y3=rnorm(10,0,1)
x=seq(1,10,1)
mat=cbind(y1,y2,y3)
a=c(1,4,7)
b=c(2,5,8)
g=c(3,6,9)
v=as.factor(paste(expression(alpha)," = ",a,", ",
                  expression(beta)," = ",b,", ",
                  expression(gamma)," = ",g))
matplot(x,mat,type="l",col=1:3,lty=1,xlab="x",ylab="mat",main="Legend Practice")
legend("bottomright",col=1:3,lty=1,legend=levels(v))
```

In the legend line, the result is coming out as "alpha = 1,beta = 2, gamma = 3" and so on, for each of the 3 lines corresponding to the 3 `y` values. How can I change this to **α = 1, β = 2, γ = 3** and so on ?

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `bquote` for this

```
matplot(x,mat,type="l",col=1:3,lty=1,xlab="x",ylab="mat",main="Legend Practice")
legend("bottomright",col=1:3,lty=1, legend=as.expression(c(
        bquote(alpha~'='~.(a[1])~', '~beta~'='~.(b[1])~', '~gamma~'='~.(g[1])),
        bquote(alpha~'='~.(a[2])~', '~beta~'='~.(b[2])~', '~gamma~'='~.(g[2])),
        bquote(alpha~'='~.(a[3])~', '~beta~'='~.(b[3])~', '~gamma~'='~.(g[3])) )))
```

[image]

This can be made compact by looping through the sequence of vectors as @d.b mentioned

```
legend("bottomright",col=1:3,lty=1, legend = as.expression(sapply(1:length(a),
  function(i) bquote(alpha~'='~.(a[i])~', '~beta~'='~.(b[i])~', '~gamma~'='~.(g[i])))))
```

Or with `mapply`

```
legend("bottomright",col=1:3,lty=1, legend = as.expression(mapply(function(x,y, z) 
       bquote(alpha~'='~.(x)~', '~beta~'='~.(y)~', '~gamma~'='~.(z)),
               a, b, g)))
```

Comment: I think `legend("bottomright",col=1:3,lty=1, legend = as.expression(sapply(1:length(a), function(i)
 bquote(alpha~'='~.(a[i])~', '~beta~'='~.(b[i])~', '~gamma~'='~.(g[i])))))` could work